# Can we release 2 flavours of app with same package name but different minSdk in playstore?

Tags: android, gradle, google-play, android-productflavors, build-variant

Below is my code of app GRADLE file where I am overriding my default configurations by setting the **flavor**.

My app is already in play store, I have to integrate **Health Connect library of google**. As per this library requirement **minimum SDK should be 26** and I want app should be available for both 26 above and 26 below android users.

Questions:

1. Will I be able to upload app to play store with same package name and different minimum SDK?
2. I have to keep Client1 and Client2 as two flavor with two builds. One with minimum SDK21 and other with minimum SDK 26.
3. I also need to manage version code for all flavor differently to release to play store.

   ```
    android {
    compileSdk 34
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.mobile.android"
        minSdk 21
        targetSdk 33
        versionCode 22
        versionName "2.2.2"
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true

        renderscriptTargetApi 22
        renderscriptSupportModeEnabled true
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
        debug{
            minifyEnabled false
        }
    }

    flavorDimensions "api","version"
    productFlavors {
        client1 {
            dimension "version"
            applicationId "com.client.one"
            targetSdk 33
            versionCode 22
            versionName "2.2.2"
            resValue "string", "app_name", "ClientOne"
            manifestPlaceholders = [
                    appIcon: "@mipmap/ic_launcher",
                    appIconRound: "@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
            ]
        }
        client2 {
            dimension "version"
            applicationId "com.client.two"
            targetSdk 33
            versionCode 1
            versionName "1.0"
            resValue "string", "app_name", "ClientTwo"
            manifestPlaceholders = [
                    appIcon: "@mipmap/ic_launcher",
                    appIconRound: "@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
            ]
        }
    minApi26 {
      dimension "api"
      minSdk 26
    }
    minApi21 {
      dimension "api"
      minSdk 21
    }
    }

    productFlavors.all {
        flavor ->
            println( flavor.name)
            defaultConfig.buildConfigField 'String', 'var_'+flavor.name, '\"'+flavor.name+'\"'
    }

    buildFeatures {
        viewBinding true
        dataBinding true
    }

    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/rxjava.properties'
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '1.8'
    }
   }
   ```

Comment: No you can't because the package name is a unique identifier for an Android app, and it must be unique on the Play Store

Comment: @user2357113 This I know package name is unique identifier for android app. But how can I manage minimum SDK 21 and 26 just because of one library of Health Connect. Minimum requirement for Health Connect library is minimum SDK 26. This is conflicting, I want my app for SDK 21(without library or exclude it) and 26 (with library) version.

Answer (score 0):

You have to choose any one of the choices. You can't provide multiple minSdks with the same package to the users. If Health Connect is important for the application, then go with minSdk 26 otherwise minSdk 21.